# LINQ Group By y let

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Estoy practicando algunos ejercicios de Group By con la Base de Datos Northwind.

Tengo la siguiente consulta Linq que funciona correctamente:

```
var Query = db.Customers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Country);

var Query2 = from g in Query
             orderby g.Count() descending
             select new { Country = g.Key, NumCustomers = g.Count() };

foreach (var g in Query2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Country: {g.Country}, NumCustomers: {g.NumCustomers}");
}
```

Luego, pretendo utilizar la cláusula let de la siguiente manera:

```
var Query = db.Customers
        .GroupBy(c => c.Country);

var Query2 = from g in Query
             let NumCustomers = g.Count()
             orderby NumCustomers descending
             select new { Country = g.Key, NumCustomers };

foreach (var g in Query2)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Country: {g.Country}, NumCustomers: {g.NumCustomers}");
}
```

Pero me lanza un error en tiempo de ejecución.
Detalle del error.

...

could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of 'Select' which contains grouping parameter without composition is not supported. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

No comprendo cómo funciona let, agradezco me pudieran orientar.

Saludos.

Comment: No estoy seguro de esto, por eso no lo coloco como respuesta. Al parecer en EF Core se cambió como opera el GroupBy, antes se ejecutaba en memoria y ahora se traduce a SQL. Seguramente si colocas var Query = db.Customers.ToList() .GroupBy(c => c.Country); debería funcionar ya que obligas a que se ejecute en memoria, y es que el problema no es de Linq si no que es de EF y la conversión que realiza a SQL, que en tu caso no sabe cómo realizarla. Supongo que en versiones posteriores de EF irán afinando este tipo de conversiones.

Comment: En todo caso, en Linq to SQL debes acostumbrarte a este tipo de escenarios. Y entender que es lo que se ejecuta en el Motor de SQL y que se ejecuta en memoria. Un caso típico es cuando colocan en una consulta Linq una función C# y la consulta les anda lento, porque hay quienes no entienden que eso no es posible ejecutarlo en SQL y por tanto EF se trae toda la data de la consulta para poder evaluar aquella función.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Efectivamente, veo que si hago var Query = db.Customer.GroupBy(c => c.Country).ToList(); sí funciona, esto implica que el ordenamiento agrupado ya no lo ejecuta el motor de la Base de Datos sino que se hace en memoria del Web-Server. Lo que aún me sigo preguntado es ¿porqué sí funciona sin la cláusula let de LINQ? cuando no utilizo dicha cláusula LINQ, no requiere hacer ToList() y toda la consulta la ejecuta el motor de Base de Datos

Comment: Es por lo que te estoy diciendo. Primero una aclaración, LINQ es un lenguaje de consulta que opera colecciones (listas, diccionarios, etc) . Un sub conjunto de LINQ es LINQ to Entities que es donde se cruza con Entitie Framework, y en este caso lo que hace es convertir lo que se puso como LINQ en una consulta SQL (una query de toda la vida). Tu encontraste una combinación usando `let`, `GroupBY` y `Count` que SI es una consulta LINQ valida (por eso funciona cuando está en memoria), pero que no es capaz de convertirla en una sentencia SQL.

Comment: Por otro lado, cuando le sacas el `let`, ahora si es capaz de convertirla. Y no es problema del let si no de la combinación de cosas. Ahora bien, yo lo veo como una curiosidad no como un problema, porque efectivamente existe una forma de realizar la misma consulta sin problema (sin el let) . A mí nunca me ha pasado, pero si me ha pasado tener que cambiar la consulta LINQ para generar otra sentencia SQL y así mejorar el performance de la consulta, entonces encuentro habitual tener que "jugar" cambiando cosas hasta encontrar la consulta LINQ adecuada